# Threading in iOS issue while returning value

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, core-location

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var lat: Double! = 0.0
    var long: Double! = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.findMyLocation()
            print(self.lat)
            print(self.long)
    }

    func findMyLocation() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // Here we start locating
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for location in locations {
            self.lat = location.coordinate.latitude
            self.long = location.coordinate.longitude
        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Here's my simple view controller to get the latitude and longitude of my current location and assign it to local variables `lat` and `long` and then `print` it. The above code always prints 0.0 for both `lat` and `long`. The reason for this is because first the `print(lat) print(long)` executes and after that the fetching of location executes. I am sure there is some really easy way to fix this issue but i am not sure how to do this. Any help appreciated. I am assuming we have to work with grand central dispatch. Please suggest what I should be looking at.

Also, I have added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to `info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only print the coordinates, after the location manager found some, i.e. in function `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`.
But you try to print them in `viewDidLoad`, when the location manager has no coordinates yet.

Comment: Yes. I do know that part. My question is if there is any way for me to wait to get the location and then print it in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: No. You have to get coordinate from the location manager, before you can print them.

Comment: isnt there like a completion handler to get the location coordinates once the location manager gets them ?

Comment: You do only **startup** the location manager in `viewDidLoad`, and the earliest callback when coordinates are available, is indeed `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`. Earlier, there are simply no coordinates available. Maybe you could explain better, why you believe to need the coordinates in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This is just an example. What i am looking for is to get the lat and long, then feed them to an API call to get the required data. I don't want to do all this in locationManager method. I know that the location manager performs location search in the background asynchronously. So what i need to understand is if there is a completion handler at the end of that location search where i can make that api call.

Comment: So, if I understand you right, you want execute your API call only once after you get the 1st coordinates from the location manager. If so, you could simply set a flag (BOOL property) in your location manager callback whether your API call has already been done. Or, if you don’t want to do it there, you could update your location property there, and use a key value observation notification when the update happens, and set the flag there.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using an operations queue with dependency here ? Or have a serial queue in place ?

Comment: Maybe now I understand: You want to do an API call, which is only possible in the main thread. So the question is from which thread `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` is called. The docs (`CLLocationManagerDelegate`) say: _The methods of your delegate object are called from the thread in which you started the corresponding location services_. So since you started the location manager from the main thread, there is no problem to call the API from the delegate function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get used to the way asynchronous operations work. They deliver their result at some point in the future.

With CLLocation, in addition there is the possibility that the user refuses you permission to get the location. Just because you want the location doesn't mean you are getting it.

So your view must be able to display something useful in all three cases: Location not known yet, location denied, and location known. And you want to implement didChangeAuthorizationStatus as well, in case your status changes from "not known" to "access denied". And each callback must be able to change the display appropriately.